# Sort Map elements in java Map<String, List<String>> in reverseorder

Tags: java, string

In my java program, i am getting result like

Output:

> acre care race
>
> act cat

Expected:

> act cat
>
> acre care race

Now I want to sort the Map elements in reverse order. So I can get the result like above. I added my code in below.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        Scanner sc = readWords();
        Map<String, List<String>> wordAnagramPairs = new HashMap<>();
        wordAnagramPairs = mapAnagrams(sc);
        Comparator<List<String>> c = (l1, l2) -> {
            Collections.sort(l1);
            Collections.sort(l2);
            int in = l1.get(0).length() - l2.get(0).length();
            if (in == 0) {
                return String.join(" ", l1).compareTo(String.join(" ", l2));
            } else {
                return in;
            }
        };
        List<List<String>> sortedList = wordAnagramPairs.values()
                .stream()
                .filter(li -> li != null && li.size() > 1)
                .sorted(c)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for(List<String> anagrams : sortedList){
            for(String anagram : anagrams){
                System.out.print(anagram + " ");
            }
            System.out.print('\n');
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your expected output, it seems you need to sort by length of the list element and then by the sorted list elements if the length is equal

To compare by element length and then list elements

```
Comparator<List<String>> c = (l1, l2) -> {
            Collections.sort(l1); // elements to be sorted
            Collections.sort(l2); // elements to be sorted
            int in = l1.get(0).length() - l2.get(0).length();
            if (in == 0) {
                return String.join(" ", l1).compareTo(String.join(" ", l2));
            } else {
                return in;
            }
        };
```

Since you want only the values to be printed you can use stream on values

```
    Map<String, List<String>> wordAnagramPairs = new HashMap<>();
    wordAnagramPairs.put("race", Arrays.asList("race", "care", "acre"));
    wordAnagramPairs.put("act", Arrays.asList("act", "cat"));
    wordAnagramPairs.values().stream()
                             .filter(li -> li != null && li.size() > 1)
                             .sorted(c)
                             .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
[act, cat]
[acre, care, race]
```

To collect the sorted results

```
    List<List<String>> sortedList = wordAnagramPairs.values().stream().filter(li -> li != null && li.size() > 1).sorted(c)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(sortedList);
```

You can also use `TreeMap<String, TreeSet<String>>` to sort the map by key and sort the values by Set value

To sort by key

```
    wordAnagramPairs.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
                    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I tried both solution but still not working. It is same result.

Comment: Did you try the first comparator? See the output, it matches your expected output.

Comment: add all inputs in the Question, also mention which one is not working

Comment: excellent, the comparator one i tried it's seems to be working. But if i remove `.forEach(System.out::println);` the result changes. Can you tell why is this happening?

Comment: `forEach` is a terminal operation, stream to work we need should have terminal operator. added a `collect` to collect the sorted list. check updated answer with collect

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code. Please can you check why it is not working functioning properly. I don't want to show  the output as array. I want to show them as element. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127985/discussion-between-mohammad-shahadat-hossain-and-saravana).

Comment: Thank you for the precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TreeMap for this without use HashMap. 
Refer this :http://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/how-to-iterate-treemap-in-reverse-order-in-java/

Unless try as this:

To sort Map:

```
Map<String, List<String>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>(Collections.reverseOrder());
sortedMap .putAll(wordAnagramPairs );
```

To sort List:
You can sort list inside for loop calling following one before iterate it.

```
Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

OR

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```